# Navigating through a TreeView using up and down button

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, treeview

I have a `TreeView` with items in it, I also created two buttons *"Move Up"* and *"Move Down"*.

Whenever any of the button is clicked, I want that the selected item in the `TreeView` will be moved up or down based on the clicked button.

Please notice that I can navigate through these items by using the *up* and *down* keyboard arrow keys.

**Q:** How can I assign my button actions to these event? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: The solution depends on your requirements.  Do you have a single level TreeView or multi-level TreeView?  Does "Move UP" and "Move Down" mean at the same level or move up down to a different level.

Comment: Yes, it's a single level TreeView. "MOVE UP" and "MOVE DOWN" is the same level. Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327079/how-can-move-up-and-move-down-selected-item-programmatically-in-treeview-in-c